# what profiles chain will be loaded if I run a shell in another shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

I know there are rules of classification to explain this like the image below.
[loading rules of profiles chain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsT1a.png)
But in my tests, it seems like it belong to none of them that if I run into another shell inside a normal shell.

```
userName is in ZSH $: echo thanks to anwsers & bash
thanks to anwsers
(scripts in /etc/profile didn't run)
userName is in Bash $:
```

Comment: One comment on that image. `/etc/bash.bashrc` is disabled by default; you need to uncomment a line in the `bash` source code and recompile to enable it.

Comment: What is a _profile chain_? What is a "normal" shell (respectively what would be a "unnormal" shell)? The startup files are dependent on the kind of shell (login-shell vs. non-login shell, interactive vs. non-interactive shell), and this can also be further influenced by certain environmentvariables depending on the type of shell.  In the case of bash, the rules for the game are defined in the chapter _INVOCATION_ in the bash man-page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `bash` being executed from `zsh`. `bash` with no options starts a non-login shell, while `/etc/profile` is only sourced by login shells. If you explicitly request a login shell with `bash -l`, it will source `/etc/profile`.

Comment: Thank u! silly me misunderstand the image.

Comment: It's an intimidating image :)